# Braintree Integration only PayPal option not a credit card option

Tags: android, braintree

I am successfully integrate Braintree SDK using there gradle file in my project. I am integarte there default Drop in UI , Now I want to show only PayPal option not a credit card option. It is possible ? If possible then please suggest me.. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Rendering only the PayPal button when using the Drop-In UI is not possible, as the Drop-In must render credit card fields at a minimum. However, you can follow the documentation on the [custom PayPal UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/android/v2#using-a-custom-ui) in order to render only a PayPal button within your app.

Comment: I have to say, braintree documentation is far from newbie friendly BTW. I have been looking for two hours on why when I click paypal button in the drop down, it doesn't come up to pay with paypal. Just goes back to my other screen.

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this by hiding pay via card option using CSS, i don't know doing this thing is appropriate or not but it's work for me !

```
<style>
    .braintree-option__card{
       display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

If you want only paypal visible with all borders, use:

```
<style>
    .braintree-option__card:not(.braintree-option__paypal) {
       display: none !important;
    }
    .braintree-option__paypal {
        border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px !important;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    }
</style>
```